# Displaced elements of navigation menu

Tags: html, css

I try to create a horizontal navigation, but there are some problems:

1. The first element is displaced
2. Is there a better way to place the Text centered below the icon. Now I did that just with a 
   . And how should I use the optional arrow-down-icon - here I used the span-tag. I think the html-markup for that is not the best.
3. And the second-level ul (=subelements) isn't shown correctly and doesn't enclose the subelements.

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/pqubgt2d/

```css
   nav {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: .3em 0;
    border-radius: 7px;
   }
   nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    height: 2.5em;
    padding: .25em;
    color: #555;
    margin: 0;
   }
   nav ul li {
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
    font-size: .5em;
    margin: .5em 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 4em;
    text-align: center;
   }
   nav ul li i {
       font-size: 3em !important;
   }
   nav ul li ul {
    font-size: 3em;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
   }

   .button-arrow-down {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid #B4B4B4;
       margin: 0 auto;
       position: relative;
       bottom: -7px;
   }
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><i class="fa fa-file-o"></i><br>New</li>
    <li>
     <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i><br>
     Save<br>
     <span class="button-arrow-down"></span>
     <ul>
      <li>Subelement 1</li>
      <li>Subelement 2</li>
      <li>Subelement 3</li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
    nav {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        padding: .3em 0;
        border-radius: 7px;
        height: 2.5em;
    }
    nav > ul {
        list-style: none;
        padding: .25em;
        color: #555;
        margin: 0;
    }
    nav > ul > li {
        font-family:"Source Sans Pro";
        font-size: .5em;
        margin: .8em;
        text-align: center;
        float:left;
        width:4em;
    }
    nav > ul > li i {
        font-size: 2.8em !important;
    }
    nav > ul > li>ul {
        font-size: 3em;
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }
    .button-arrow-down {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-left: 5px solid transparent;
        border-right: 5px solid transparent;
        border-top: 5px solid #B4B4B4;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
        bottom: -7px;
    }
    .drop {
        float:left;
        display:none;
    }
    li:hover > .drop {
        display:block;
    }
    .drop {
        list-style-type:none;
        font-family:"Source Sans Pro";
        font-size: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="item"><i class="fa fa-file-o"></i>New</li>
        <li class="item"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>Save<span class="button-arrow-down"></span>

            <ul class="drop">
                <li>Subelement 1</li>
                <li>Subelement 2</li>
                <li>Subelement 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Try this. This looks more like you want it. If it helps +1.
Edit. I have updated the answer due to your comment.

Comment: No. The subelements are in a dropdown-menu of the second element (="Save")

Comment: Did it work? If it did,accept it. If not, ask me more.

Comment: Nearly. The description ("New" and "Save") should be centered and below the icon. The arrow should be centered below the description.